# F2FS on raw flash devices

Tags: filesystems, flash-memory

I've read that F2FS is not used on raw flash devices. My question is: can it be? If not, why not? What can possibly prevent a filesystem from being used on a storage medium?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://lwn.net/Articles/518988/,

> Unlike jffs2 and logfs, f2fs is not targeted at raw flash devices, but rather at the specific hardware that is commonly available to consumers — SSDs, eMMC, SD cards, and other flash storage with an FTL (flash translation layer) already built in.

It seems to me that the hardware requirement to use f2fs (FTL) is what bars raw flash from using f2fs. Read further into the article, and you will find this:

> As the FTL typically uses a log-structured design to provide the wear-leveling and write-gathering that flash requires, this means that there are two log structures active on the device — one in the firmware and one in the operating system. f2fs is explicitly designed to make use of this fact and leaves a number of tasks to the FTL while focusing primarily on those tasks that it is well positioned to perform. So, for example, f2fs makes no effort to distribute writes evenly across the address space to provide wear-leveling.

This might explain why raw flash is unable to use f2fs: the FTL is required to use this file system.

Answer (score 1):

F2FS does not support the work of FTL.

Flash memory needs a special layer, FTL, to support the limitation of flash memory, such as no in-place update. However, F2FS basically believes that there is a FTL on the flash memory.

If you want to use a file system on a raw device, you should use a file system for a raw devices.